# Run multiple script files SQL with a TransactSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

I'll be thankful if we could continue the subject discussed on the post of the link below which treats of: run multiples script files on a database the sql server.

[TransactSQL to run another TransactSQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237198/transactsql-to-run-another-transactsql-script/18260612)

Here in my company we have a similar problem. We have two environments: pre-production and production. When we are developing new releases, a lot of changes are made in pre-production database which is a smallest copy of production. These changes generates a set of scripts files (*.sql files that can have CREATE, ALTER VIEWS, TABLES, INSERT and others commands) and we try to control then by using the SVN (we know the file names). When we have to publish this modifications, these scripts are executed one by one on the production database.

The problem is, we (developers team) do not have permissions to run scripts on the production database, this is made by the DBA and on the most of times, one of these scripts have errors that can causes a momentary system crash.

There is a way to use the solution discussed on this post to run an atomic execution of all the script files and if something get wrong, we do a rollback? Maybe using the BEGIN TRANS, COMMIT and ROLLBACK statements.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to have another test environment before production where your deployment can be tested. This works quite well.

Comment: Tks @SpectralGhost, we have this possibility but in this case we need a process for constantly do a restore of this test environment. Why?  Imagine whe run a set of script that changes the databases but it has errors or something, we need to restore the database with the original data (production) because all the script set have to run once, when we publish in the  production environment, but ok it is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

if Visual Studio Schema Compare is available it can be used on these enviroment migration.

Check some concepts shown in [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148354/visual-studio-database-project-rollback-script)

Regards.