# Make roll-off script using Visual Studio 2022 Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2022, database-project

I have a Visual Studio 2022 database project.

Here it is super easy to compare to a database and create a roll-on script.

But when when I switch the compare view around so my source is my database and my target is my project then I cannot create the rollback script. The create script button is disabled.

Is there another trick to create roll-off scripts using Visual Studio 2022 Database Projects?

[Answer for VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148354/visual-studio-database-project-rollback-script)

Comment: A/B deploys might be your best bet. Either that or use branches for your version control. So you can flip between your "story" branch and your "release" branch to generate scripts.  I'd be _really_ careful w/ rollback scripts generated this way, though. You'll get schema changes, but could have data loss along the way.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will use master branch against QA database, after deploy, generate it then.